# Disable multi-select in jquery autoSuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am getting data from server and loading them to JQuery auto suggest. It's works fine. But I don't know how to configure it. I Initialize my text box to it. Now i need when user select one value from it, He will be not able to choose another value of he cant enter a word, except he can delete old value.

Here is my code :-

```
        $(document).ready(function(e){
          //handle auto suggestion when compose message
          var user_ids = {};
          //var hidden_user_ids = $('input:hidden[name=user_ids]');
          var url = '/account/insiderName';
          var conf = {
            selectedItemProp: 'name',
            searchObjProps: 'name',
            asHtmlID: 'insider_ids',
            neverSubmit: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            preFill: ',' //, {{attributes: {name: 'joe', value: '12345'}, num: '1'}},

          };
          $('.insiderUser').autoSuggest(url, conf);
        });
```

Here is my text Box Code:-

```
    <div class="field to"><input type="text" name="toInsider" value=""    class="insiderUser"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this configuration option also:

```
selectionLimit: 1
```

since it defaults to `false`, which means no limit.

From the docs: https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you. I will accept this answer after 2 minute.